# Extension Point for images

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to create an extension point for images. What I am thinking is that the user should give the a name an id and the path of the image but after that how can I create the image. When a class is given in the extensions the createExecutableExtension can be used and create the object. But having only the path for the image how it can be implemented. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that:

```
// configuration element is the handle of your extension-point
    String contributor = configurationElement.getContributor().getName();
    String path = configurationElement.getAttribute("path");
    InputStream openStream = FileLocator.openStream(Platform.getBundle(contributor), new Path(path), false);
    Image image = new Image(null, openStream);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer your solution seems to be what I want. Actually, my problem was with the bundle. I didn't knew how it works. Finally, what I did...for each extension the user has to provide a class that implements an interface and with this class the bundle and the path are provided by the user - contibutor. Probably your solution is better. I will try this if I find time.